# How to load MobileNet weights with an input tensor in Keras

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to apply transfer learning to MNIST using MobileNet weights in Keras. Keras documentation to use MobileNet https://keras.io/applications/#mobilenet

Mobilenet accepts 224x224x3 as input but MNIST is 28x28x1. I'm creating a Lambda layer which can convert 28x28x1 image into 224x224x3 and send it as input to MobileNet. The following code causes

TypeError: Input layers to a `Model` must be `InputLayer` objects. Received inputs: Tensor("lambda_2/ResizeNearestNeighbor:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32). Input 0 (0-based) originates from layer type `Lambda`.

```
height = 28
width = 28
input_image = Input(shape=(height,width,1))

def resize_image_to_inception(x):
    x = K.repeat_elements(x, 3, axis=3)
    x = K.resize_images(x, 8, 8, data_format="channels_last")
    return x

input_image_ = Lambda(resize_image_to_inception, output_shape=(224, 224, 3))(input_image)
print(type(input_image_))
base_model = MobileNet(input_tensor=input_image_, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can apply `Lambda` layer once you have an input which happens to be an `Input` layer. So, you should use PIL to resize your images and then send to the input layer. There would be no need of `lambda` layer

Comment: Yeah, that's a good suggestion. But that is not ideal as it would require us to size up the images when it's not really necessary.

Comment: Why would you require to size up? This all resizing things will be happening on the copy of image only

Comment: Upsizing images offline would increase the memory consumption.

50000x224x224x3 which is ~7.5G of RAM. Specifying upsizing as a Lambda layer would only increase BATCH_SIZEx224x224x3 bytes

Comment: Umm I can't reproduce this error. The code did throw an error, but it's different from yours. It works after I added `input_shape=(224, 224, 3)` when creating `MobileNet`. Which Keras version are you working on?

Comment: You have to add input_tensor. Because we are adding a lambda layer to convert an image from 28x28x1 to 224x224x3.

Comment: I'm on keras "2.1.1"

Comment: My code https://pastebin.com/9Efc7UXg
My error: https://pastebin.com/xFZKNB5s

ValueError: If imagenet weights are being loaded, input must have a static square shape (one of (128,128), (160,160), (192,192), or (224, 224)). Input shape provided = (None, None, 3)

Comment: So it's not the error you've mentioned in your question, that's what I'm confused about. I did added the `input_tensor` btw. Try also add `input_shape=(224, 224, 3)` to the function call.

Comment: That won't solve the purpose right? Then we have to convert images from 28x28x3 to 224x224x3 offline and it will bloat up the memory

Comment: No, I mean add it to the `MobileNet` call: `MobileNet(input_tensor=input_image_, weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))`. Add **both** `input_tensor` and `input_shape`. The input shape of the final model is still `(28, 28, 1)` defined in `Input`.

Comment: "base_model = MobileNet(input_tensor=input_image_, input_shape=(224,224,3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)"

Comment: TypeError: Input layers to a `Model` must be `InputLayer` objects. Received inputs: Tensor("lambda_1/ResizeNearestNeighbor:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32). Input 0 (0-based) originates from layer type `Lambda`.


I still get this error.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MAw58Usi

Comment: It's a bug in this line `model = Model(inputs=input_image_, outputs=predict)`. You should use `input_image`, not `input_image_`.